# await and returning to the caller

Tags: c#, async-await

If I have an async method :

```
public async Task MyMethodAsync()
{
   // [.. Some synchronous code here ..]

   await AnotherAsyncMethod();
}
```

And at some point in my code I call it like that :

```
await MyMethodAsync();
```

Will this statement immediately return to the caller without even entering the MyMehodAsync ? I guess so but not sure.

If I want the call to `MyMethodAsync` to first execute the `[.. Some synchronous code here ..]` part immediately, should I rather do :

```
var t = MyMethodAsync(); 
await t;
```

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
[.. Some synchronous code here ..]
```

will execute synchronously until the first await yields control. You're doing it right. Your last example is exactly the same as your previous in terms of what gets executed synchronously.

Answer (score 5):

When your code calls

```
await MyMethodAsync();
```

then execution *will* enter `MyMethodAsync` (synchronously). The method only "pauses" when/if `MyMethodAsync` returns an uncompleted `Task`.

You may find my [`async`/`await` intro post helpful](http://nitoprograms.blogspot.com/2012/02/async-and-await.html).

Comment: Key explanation here is: _"The method only "pauses" when/if MyMethodAsync returns an uncompleted Task."_ The `await` keyword does not do this alone and totally had me thrown off.